calulcate size of each file in each directory using pyspark and add as a column
I have files in each directory inside a Azure storage account(devcome) which has the cointainer (inputdata) for example
devcome
inputdata
    abc
        01
            Module191.json
            Module192.json
        02
            Module191.json
            Module192.json
    def
        03
            Module191.json
            Module192.json
        04
            Module191.json
            Module192.json

I am supposed to find the size of each file and add to the dataframe i am reading with:
i am using the below script
def get_json_file_size(json_data):
    import json
    json_bytes = [json.dumps(row).encode('utf-8') for row in json_data]
    return sum(len(row) for row in json_bytes)
    
spark.udf.register("get_json_file_size_udf", get_json_file_size)

df = spark.read.format("json") \
.load(f"abfss://inputdata@devcome.dfs.core.windows.net/{abc,def}/*/*/*/") \
.withColumn("file_name", input_file_name()) \
.withColumn("file_data_size", expr("get_json_file_size_udf(file_name)"))

I am unsure where i am getting it wrong since the file size is something which is not matching.
can i have some advice
